# Making my FTP accessible from the internet

Tags: ftp

I have an FTP server created in Filezilla with IP-192.168.0.99, "Listen to these ports is set to 28256.

On the local network, I can use 192.168.0.99:28256 to log in to my ftp.

How can I log in to the ftp from outside the local network?

- Router firewall is disabled
- Windows Firewall is disabled
- Router allows me to setup a virtual server with the following details:

  1. Service port XX-XX or XX
  2. Internal port
  3. IP address
  4. Protocol - TCP/UDP
  5. Status - Enabled/Disabled

I've tried setting up numerous things on the virtual server, that should be the forwarding but nothing allows me to connect from another IP to the FTP. What am I missing?

Comment: FTP is a strange beast requiring both a control channel and a data channel. The data channel uses dynamic ports. That is configured in your FTP server. You’ll need to forward the control port as you said and the entire range of data ports.

Comment: Even doing that doesn't seem to allow me to access the ftp from another network. Trying Service port 20-60000, Internal port - 28256, IP as above, protocol TCP. It doesn't seem to be working. I think I am missing something else.

Comment: I’m assuming you have obtained and are using your public IP address when you test? Your ISP may not allow you to run servers on your internet connection. It could be carrier grade NAT.

Comment: After going through pretty much everything, I believe it is the carrier that's causing that. They just don't allow hosting servers. I will check with them. Just an update, I managed to make the forwarding to some point, where the IP was recognized but the ports were still not allowed. It said I am behind NAT router even when I plugged in the cable and disconnected my own router.

Comment: It might be Carrier-Grade NAT, where the carrier does NAT at their border. This has become common as IPv4 address space was depleting, because ISPs couldn't get enough IPs for their customers.

Comment: You can tell if this is going on by doing a traceroute to a public server. If you see private IPs in the first few hops, that's what they're doing.